# Display dynamic JSON content using jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm following through an example which deals with the following json object passed from a php page:-

```
 {"book":[{"title":"Harry Potter","author":"J K. Rowling","year":"2005","price":"29.99"},{"title":"Learning XML","author":"Erik T. Ray","year":"2003","price":"39.95"}]}
```

I know  that you can iterate through and print all the data to a table as follows:

```
$.each(data.book, function(index, book) {
                    content = '<tr><td>' + book.title + '</td>';
                    content += '<td>' + book.author + '</td>';
                    content += '<td>' + book.year + '</td>';
                    content += '<td>' + book.price + '</td></tr>';
                    $(content).appendTo("#content2");
                });
```

But say the json data is dynamic following the same structure, how can I adapt the above code to work for this? I was thinking I would need some sort of nested loop.

Whats causing me confusion is that for the line $.each(data.book, function(index, book) {
data.book will not always be data.book they would be data.foo
and the lines which refer to book.title will not always be the same it could be book.bar

Any guidance most appreciated

Comment: If you're not too tied to a layout, why not use JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it in a nested loop like this

```
var content = '';
$.each(data.book, function(index, book) {
    content += '<tr>';
    $.each(book,function(k,v){
        content += '<td>' + v + '</td>';
    });
    content += '</tr>';   
});
$(content).appendTo("#content2");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tjjQh/

Oh.. then use the for in loop

```
for (v in data) {
    $.each(data[v], function(index, book) {
        content += '<tr>';
        $.each(book, function(k, v) {
            content += '<td>' + v + '</td>';
        });
        content += '</tr>';
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8YCgA/
​

Comment: Thanks for this but not quite what I'm after. For example if the data is the json string is dynamic the loop would need to cater for this

Comment: oh guess i was confused by this line assuming the structure will be the same `But say the json data is dynamic following the same structure,`

Comment: @mjsey are you saying the structure does change then?  like data.foo is going to have a different structure than data.books?

Comment: Yes but what I meant was that the structure may not be books , it could be for example cars.

Comment: yeah.. then pass in data.cars or data.foo instead of data.book and it will still work..

Comment: but if the data is dynamic how would I know whether its data.cars and not data.books as data.foo is unknown?

Comment: @mjsey I updated my answer on how you can dynamically do that also.  I didn't know that was what you wanted

Comment: @mjsey is that what you were asking for?

Comment: @mjsey in your code? are you able to make a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Got it working, just needed another iteration. Thanks for your advice

Answer (score -1):

You may want to check out [jQuery Templating](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-an-introduction-to-jquery-templating/).

```
var data = [  
        { name : "John",  age : 25 },  
        { name : "Jane",  age : 49 },  
        { name : "Jim",   age : 31 },  
        { name : "Julie", age : 39 },  
        { name : "Joe",   age : 19 },  
        { name : "Jack",  age : 48 }
```

Can be expressed as:

```
<li>  
    <span>{%= $i + 1 %}</span>  
    <p><strong>Name: </strong> {%= name %}</p>  
    {% if ($context.options.showAge) {  %}  
        <p><strong>Age: </strong> {%= age %}</p>  
    {% } %}  
</li>
```

Comment: The OP was referring to dynamic data, this answer although related isn't quite what he's looking for.